# What font does Vox use for their videos?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What's the name of this thick, bold font that Vox uses mostly for their videos? I'm working on a poster, and I feel like this font would really work with it, so I would love to know the name of the font.
If you could help me it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Font Image]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from a small image, but it seems to be a bold weight of [Balto](https://typesupply.com/fonts/balto), which Vox uses for body text.